# Como escolher o primeiro form a ser exibido?

Tags: c#, winforms

Quando executo meu projeto, sempre é aberto o fmPrincipal, porém, resolvi criar um fmLogin para ser exibido primeiro e o usuário fazer login nele.

Como faço pra configurar pro fmLogin ser exibido primeiro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No seu método `Main()`, chame `Application.Run(new fmLogin());`, passando como parâmetro uma nova instância do `fmLogin`.

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new fmLogin());
}
```

Assim, a aplicação irá iniciar pelo `fmlogin()`.